# IcmpSendEcho2 - Asynchronous invocation is not asynchronous

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using [IcmpSendEcho2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366051%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to send an ICMP echo request to a host I would like to check. However, I need to handle the response asynchronously in a separate receiver thread.

In order to accomplish that, I create a new Windows event handle (`CreateEvent`) for every request I send out. The receiving thread will be notified and waits for incoming replies using `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

This event notification system works fine, but I cannot get `IcmpSendEcho2` to be invoked asynchronously. The MSDN says that

> The IcmpSendEcho2 function is called asynchronously when either the ApcRoutine or Event parameters are specified.

I do specify the *Event* parameter, but the calling thread is still locked until either a response arrived or the *Timeout* time has passed. I would expect that the method returns immediately and the supplied event gets signaled as soon as a response arrives or the timeout time has passed. At least that's my understanding of "asynchronous".

This is my invocation of the function, the parameters provided are valid:

```
dwResult = IcmpSendEcho2(
    icmpFileHandle,
    eventHandle,
    NULL, //no apcRoutine   
    NULL, //no apcContext
    ((sockaddr_in*)addrInfo->ai_addr)->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr,
    &requestData,
    sizeof(requestData),
    &requestOptions,
    &icmp4ReplyBuffer,
    sizeof(icmp4ReplyBuffer),
    30000);
```

Does the MSDN have a different understanding of "asynchronous", or is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366051%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The IcmpSendEcho2 function sends an IPv4 ICMP echo request and returns
>   either immediately (if Event or ApcRoutine is non-NULL) or returns
>   after the specified time-out. The ReplyBuffer contains the ICMP echo
>   responses, if any.

Your understanding of asynchronous is correct, and it should return immediately if you passed a non-NULL event.

If it isn't working as expected, there are 3 possibilities:

1. Your `eventHandle` is NULL, meaning the `CreateEvent` failed and returned a NULL handle. Have you checked?
2. You're closing the ICMP file handle (`IcmpCloseHandle`) right after the asynchronous `IcmpSendEcho` call (**suggested by OP in comments**).
3. If you're running a firewall application, it could be hooking that API and unintentionally breaking the asynchronous requirement.
4. You could have found a Windows bug.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1. If my eventHandle was actually NULL, I believe WaitForMultipleObjects would not receive an event and return the correct index in the event handle array. However, I just double-checked and can tell for sure than my event handle is definitely not NULL.

2. What exactly do you mean by "firewall application"? If it means that the Windows Firewall interferes, I tried disabling that and running the application with elevated rights, didn't help.

3. I would believe that somebody would have noticed before me. I should report this issue in some official Microsoft forum, then.

Comment: 1) Nice. 2) Ok, that was unlikely, but I have seen firewalls using API hooks in the past. 3) Probably yes. Would you prepare & post a minimal working (compiling) code, so we can reproduce the problem? And which Windows version are you using?

Comment: Maybe add option 4: do _not_ close the Icmp file handle (IcmpCloseHandle) directly after an asynchronous IcmpSendEcho call. I failed to reproduce this when creating a minimal example and noticed that I did just that, and apparently in such a case, IcmpCloseHandle will lock until an event occured (timeout or reply). So, this was definitely my mistake, but unexpected. The weirdest problems always have the most simple causes... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Good job! :) Updated the answer according to your suggestion.